# Cannot read property 'home' of undefined

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I'm very new to backbone.js and requirejs and I'm trying to figure out the following situation.

When I load my app in chrome during "context.onScriptLoad" the initialize function of my router is called. Here I'm using my app controller but it's still undefined. So, I'm getting an error saying:

```
Cannot read property 'home' of undefined
```

My router defined as:

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'components/appController'],

    function ($, _, Backbone, appController) {

        var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                '': 'home',
                'details/:id': 'details',
                'createAgent': 'createAgent'
            },

            initialize: function () {

                var routeName;

                for (var r in this.routes) {
                    routeName = this.routes[r];

                    this.route(r, routeName, $.proxy(appController[routeName], appController));
                }
            },

            start: function () {
                Backbone.history.start();
            }

        });

        return new Router();
    }
);
```

It seems that appController is not initialized.

The controller is defined as:

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'],
    function ($, _, Backbone) {
        var appController = {
            currentView: null,

            home: function () {
                var self = this;
                require(['views/homeView'], function (HomeView) {
                    var View = new HomeView();
                    self.renderView.call(self, View);
                });
            },

            details: function (id) {
                var self = this;
                require(['views/detailsView'], function (DetailsView) {
                    var Agent = app.Agents.get(id);

                    var View = new DetailsView({ model: Agent });
                    self.renderView.call(self, View);
                });
            },

            createAgent: function () {
                var self = this;

                require(['views/createView'], function (CreateView) {
                    var View = new CreateView();
                    self.renderView.call(self, View);
                });
            },

            renderView: function (View) {
                this.currentView && this.currentView.remove();

                $('#main').html(View.render().el);
                this.currentView = View;
            }
        }
    });
```

My app.js is

```
requirejs.config({

    baseUrl: 'scripts/libs',

    paths: {
        models: '../models',
        collections: '../collections',
        views: '../views',
        routers: '../routers',
        components: '../components',
        modalDialog: 'backbone.ModalDialog'
    },

    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },

        'underscore': { exports: '_' }
    }
})


var app = app || {};

require(['routers/router', 'components/dataService'], function (Router, dataService) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        dataService.getData();

        Router.start();
    });
});
```

Can someone explain how I could resolve this issue?

Comment: Wouldn't your controller file need to return the `appController` so that require.js can pass it around? BTW, the "controller" things you have would normally be part of the router itself, then Backbone will automatically hook up the things in the `routes` object.

Answer (score 0):

your controller must "return AppController;"